# Installing Flutter with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am trying to install Futter with Android Studio 3.2.1. I have installed the Dart and Flutter plugins, however, even after several restarts of AS, I do not see any mention of the "New Flutter Project" wizard.

The solutions I found elsewhere on StackOverflow just say to uninstall and reinstall the plugins, always restarting AS, but this has not worked for me.

Upon the advice of @GoPro I ran Futter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v1.1.2-pre.30, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
X Android license status unknown.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3)
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.15.1)
X Flutter extension not installed; install from
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
[!] Connected device
! No devices available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some help from @GoPro I did a little more searching and found one user who had the same issue. This user had also tried uninstall/reinstall of the Flutter and Dart plugins and that did not work for him, neither for me.

Finally I found ione user who had discovered that the "Android APK Support" plugin was not enabled. This was my case also, I enabled that plugin and after an Android Studio restart I now have access to the New Flutter Project wizard.